# Team Foundation Server: How to configure workspaces for two applications that share assemblies?

Tags: tfs, dependencies, workspace

I have a question about Workspaces on TFS. Currently, I am using TFS 2008 (though I will soon be migrating to TFS 2010), and I have two workspaces:

- Workspace1
- Workspace2

Workspace1 and Workspace2 each contain different applications, which have different purposes, different user-bases, different developers that work on them, etc. And so, it was decided that these two applications should reside in their own workspaces, in order to support separate build management, seperate permissions, etc. However, some poor planing in the past has created a dependency on Workspace2 from within Workspace1. In order for the application inside Workspace1 to compile, it needs to reference some assemblies inside Workspace 2. So, it looks like this today:

- Workspace1

  - References to Workspace1 Assemblies AND Workspace2 Assemblies
- Workspace2

  - References to Workspace2 Assemblies

Now, I would like to see if there is a "best" way to try to accomplish the following:

- Have each workspace contain everything that the code inside of it
  needs in order to compile and run.
- Have the applications in both workspaces both reference the shared
  assemblies from a central place.

I know these two goals conflict with one another, but I am having a hard time deciding what to do about it. Perhaps my whole problem is that I'm using workspaces wrong. Or, perhaps I'm using them correctly, and there's no real answer to this problem. I don't know.

So, my question is really threefold:

1. Did this make sense to anyone else?
2. What am I doing wrong that is leading me into this situation?
3. If you were in this situation, what would you do about it?

Comment: This is not uncommon for me, in a few of my projects I want to make two different projects share a common subset of code. However, I'm not sure what Microsoft's definition of "Workspace" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Pull the common code out into its own project
2. Automated builds of this new project will deploy the resulting assemblies into a folder on a file share
3. Both of the existing projects will reference the common code from the share

Binaries are not source, and should not be checked into source control (IMHO).

Comment: "Binaries are not source, and should not be checked into source control (IMHO)" ... I think that's probably the crux of my problem. I'm treating binaries as source, and it's becoming painful to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends on what sort of reference Workspace 1 has on Workspace 2. If the assemblies that are referenced are in a "3rd Party" style - by that I mean, not updated very often and have a fairly unchanging API, in the same way referencing a library off the internet would. If that is the case, I would check in the binaries build in Workspace 2 into Workspace 1 in a folder where they can be referenced. Whenever updates are done to Workspace 2 binaries, check out the files in Workspace 1, copy the built ones over the top and check them in.

If the Code and API of the Workspace 2 assemblies are often changing, then you have 2 choices.

1. You can either try and combine the 2 workspace together (not sure how easy that is).
2. You can try and branch the referenced binaries from Workspace 2 into Workspace 1. There's information on how to do this [here](http://tfsguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chapter%206%20-%20Managing%20Source%20Control%20Dependencies%20in%20Visual%20Studio%20Team%20System&referringTitle=Home), but there are limitations such as the fact that you cannot branch Workspace 1 (to make a release / feature branch) whilst it has the branch with Workspace 2.

Comment: That said and done, we are planning on meeting with a company who specialise in this sort of thing tomorrow to make sure we have it right :o.

Comment: Thanks, DaveShaw. In my case, the code inside Workspace2 that is referenced is often changed. And, I am not sure option 2, which you described, will work for me if I can't branch Workspace1 afterward, but I'll look at the resource you cited. Regarding option 1, is it possible to merge workspaces like that? If so, can it be done without losing history, etc?

Comment: Also, if it's not too much to ask, if you learn anything new after your consultation tomorrow, could you give us an update here? I know I'd appreciate it, and I probably won't be the only one.

Comment: I don't know if Option #1 is possible, sorry, but if the two are that closely coupled, "I think" the source code should be together. I looked at Option #2 for us, and I when I trialled it, I could no longer create a branch of Workspace 1 unless I removed the link to Workspace 2. And if I learn anything tomorrow, I will update here (we have many projects that have varying level of dependencies on each other).

Answer (score 1):

from long time ago I spend a lot of time to find the best structure of files in the source control and after reading the p&p guide it show me all what I need like Structuring Projects and Solutions in Source Control, branch and merge Strategy, Managing Source Control Dependencies in Visual Studio Team System, and many other useful things, you can download it from codeplex, click on the following link
http://tfsguide.codeplex.com/

Comment: Voted up for the great resource citation.

Answer (score 1):

You have several choices all have trade offs.

1. Split the "shared code" out into a seperate TFS project. as John said have each dependant app reference from the drop location of the shared project's build.
2. Place the "shared code" in the project with which it is most in sequence with from a development/release cycle. By that I mean the project with which it shares a common development team, common release cycle, and common work item specifications. Have other projects that are dependant reference the assembly from this projects drop location.
3. Place all projects that "share" code with the common library in the one TFS project, along with the "shared code". If necessary create seperate builds for each VS solution. Even lock down ability to checkin to the shared solution/project if that is necessary.